# Open web url link in browser in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I want to load webpage that link I fetched through web service. I have tried myself but result is not in favour.

From server I was getting this kind of url:
http://www.simrishamn.se/sv/kultur_fritid/osterlens_museum/

Also I have used this type of code to load the page:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://" + urlSting.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

But when I test this code in device, its showing like this:

[image]

Please give some help to load fetched web url.

**EDIT:**
After doing suggested changes, not web browser not opening though button click event is working, check below image for more clearance:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173964/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-siddharth).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to check

like this

```
if let url = URL(string: urlSting.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Also try removing and/or adding `https://` prefix,
and if does not work then simply do:

```
if let url = URL(string: urlSting), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: In my experience the `https://` is required

Answer (score 6):

Please try this.

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   } else {                                            
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
   }
}
```